# MYSQL - SELECT from multiple rows, same user, different values

Tags: mysql

Below is my table called fittest.  I need to find which students based on student id (studid) have taken the pre and post test as designated in the prepost column.  So based on the simple table below I would need to return studid 123456.  How do I write the SELECT query for this?

```
SQL query: SELECT studid, prepost FROM `fittest` LIMIT 0, 30 ; 

    studid  prepost
    123456  pre
    123456  post
    1031460 pre
```

Comment: what you have tried so far? show us your query and let us know where you are facing problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT studid
  FROM fittest
 GROUP BY studid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT prepost) = 2
```

or if you want to ensure that only ids that have exactly one row with `pre` and  one row with `post` then you can enforce it like this

```
SELECT studid
  FROM fittest
 GROUP BY studid
HAVING (MAX(prepost = 'pre' ) + 
        MAX(prepost = 'post')) = 2
   AND COUNT(DISTINCT prepost) = 2
```

Output:

```
| STUDID |
----------
| 123456 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c48b0/5)** demo for both queries

Comment: @Luv : OP have only option as pre and post ONLY.

Comment: @Luv I believe OP has only `pre` and `post` values in real life. But I've added a query that eliminates possibilities of having rows with values other than pre and post.

Comment: Thank you peterm and everyone that contributed!!  The suggestions have been much appreciated.  I used your first example peterm.  The only options for prepost is pre or post.

Answer (score 4):

What about a JOIN:

```
select s1.studid, s1.prepost, s2.prepost
from fittest s1
inner join fittest s2
    on s1.studid = s2.studid
where s1.prepost = 'pre' 
  and s2.prepost = 'post'
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
    select f1.studid
       from fittest f1
       inner join fittest f2
         on f1.studid = f2.studid
    where f1.prepost = 'pre' and f2.prepost = 'post'
```

here's the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cbe6c/4)

Comment: this will never give any output

Comment: @downvoter : wrong query doesn't mean for downvote... **PLEASE**

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your real Primary Key, you use the following:

```
SELECT studid
FROM fittest
WHERE prepost = 'pre' OR prepost = 'post'
GROUP BY studid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT prepost) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.studid
FROM fittest t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.studid=t2.studid
WHERE t1.prepost = 'pre'
AND t2.prepost='post'
```

Comment: I agree with you. peterm's answer seems more performant. I left my answer for information purpose, but it's definitely not the best one.

Answer (score 0):

If Only PRE and POST are possible in this column then try

```
SELECT studid FROM fittest group by studid
HAVING Min(prepost)<>max(prepost)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
studid 
FROM `fittest` 
where prepost = 'pre' 
or prepost = 'post'
group by studid
having count(distinct prepost)=2
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a18e3/2)** with Extra records.

Comment: I don't think this will have any output... `where prepost = 'pre' 
and prepost = 'post'` will fail every time as that is not possible...

Comment: @peterm : I agree this is much buggy query I would say oppose to your query... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c999/1

Comment: Thanks for helping me in learning something which I was not aware of. But i have edited my Answer now.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `JOIN`

```
SELECT a.studid 
FROM fittest a 
JOIN fittest b 
    ON a.studid=b.studid 
        and a.prepost like 'pre' 
        and b.prepost like 'post'
```

Answer (score -1):

Select .... where studid in (123456,123457,...)

Comment: 'based on studid'
SELECT studid, prepost FROM `fittest` where studid in (123456,123457,...)

Comment: 'I need to find which students based on student id (studid)'

Comment: What is there that you don't understand?

Comment: Read the **whole** question then: "... have taken the pre and post test".