# How to select customers that only bought A and B without a subquery

Tags: sql, t-sql, where-clause

How do I create a SQL query that shows people who bought product A and who bought product B without using a subquery. Right now I am trying `Where Product IN ('A' , 'B' )`, without count distinct because I also need that information. Any ideas? Right now I am getting any A's and any B's. I want it to look like

```
JIM 03/20/2014 Product A
JIM 03/20/2014 Product B
```

And exclude anyone who doesn't purchase both.
It currently looks like

```
SELECT First, Last, Date, Product
From TABLE1
Where (Date = @Today) AND (Product IN ('A' and 'B'))
```

(Also A and B are the only options in the product table)

Comment: Please show your table structure and the query.

Comment: You are missing a closing bracket at the end of your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: do you mean `(Product IN ('A', 'B'))`? the logical `AND` of two non-null strings will be `TRUE`.

Comment: Also, (not that it matters hugely for this) what flavour of SQL are you using?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17803830/mysql-select-from-multiple-rows-same-user-different-values

Answer (score 2):

Use `group` and `having` with a condition that requires both products to have been purchased:

```
SELECT First, Last, Date
From TABLE1
Where Date = @Today
AND Product IN ('A', 'B')
GROUP BY First, Last, Date
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Product) = 2
```

The key is adding `DISTINCT` to the `COUNT()`, which changes the result from the simple number of transactions to the number of *different* products purchased.

Comment: As written, this will never return a row because `COUNT(DISTINCT Product)` in this query will never evaluate to 2.

Comment: @AndriyM is correct, the `Product` should be removed from the `GROUP BY` list.

Comment: @AndriyM quite right. Copy paste is a two-edged sword. thx

Comment: @ypercube as are you (correct)

Comment: COUNT(DISTINCT Product) does result in 0 rows. The Product is not in the group by. How can this be fixed?

Comment: What do you mean exactly?